# Array::Heap using custom comparison function

Tags: perl, heap

I was experimenting with `Array::Heap` module and wanted to create a heap sorted in reverse order. So I created this code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Array::Heap;

my @heap;
make_heap_cmp {$b <=> $a} @heap;
push_heap_cmp {$b <=> $a} @heap, 4;
push_heap_cmp {$b <=> $a} @heap, 1;
push_heap_cmp {$b <=> $a} @heap, 5;
push_heap_cmp {$b <=> $a} @heap, 7;
push_heap_cmp {$b <=> $a} @heap, 2;

while (my $val = pop_heap_cmp {$b <=> $a} @heap)
{
    print "$val\n";
}
```

It is correct, it outputs 7, 5, 4, 2, 1.

But the code looks ugly: I repeated the comparison function for every single call. Unfortunately, [module docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Heap) lack examples of use cases for special comparison function. Can somebody tell me, whether it's possible to improve this code or suggest a better module, implementing heaps?

Comment: ug, what a poor interface.

Comment: `make_heap_cmp {$b <=> $a} @heap;` doesn't do anything since `@heap` is empty.

Comment: Note that you'll need `while (defined(my $val = pop_heap_cmp {$b <=> $a} @heap))` if the heal can contain the value `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what subs are for.

```perl
my $rev = sub { $b <=> $a };

sub make_heap_rev(\@)  { &make_heap_cmp($rev, @_) }
sub push_heap_rev(\@@) { &push_heap_cmp($rev, @_) }
sub pop_heap_rev(\@)   { &pop_heap_cmp($rev, @_) }
```

Then you can use

```perl
my @heap = ( 4, 1, 5, 7, 2 );
make_heap_rev @heap;
while (my $val = pop_heap_rev @heap) {
   say $val;
}
```

or

```perl
my @heap;
push_heap_rev @heap, 4, 1, 5, 7, 2;
while (my $val = pop_heap_rev @heap) {
   say $val;
}
```

Comment: Can you recommend another module for heaps?

Answer (score 3):

Put your code in a loop:

```
my @heap;

for my $i (4, 1, 5, 7, 2) {
  push_heap_cmp {$b <=> $a} @heap, $i;
}
```

Or hide the complexity away in a subroutine;

```
sub add_to_heap {
   my ($heap, $add) = @_;

   push_heap_cmp { $b <=> $a } @$heap, $add;
}

my @heap;

for my $i (4, 1, 5, 7, 2) {
  add_to_heap \@head, $i;
}
```